# OSX: clang / ld says it can't find a static library even though it exists and all parameters are correct

Tags: c++, linker, clang, ld

I know it's going to be a silly mistake, and I'm aware that there are similar posts however none have helped so far, so I'm resorting to a new post.

I'm trying to compile the simplest GLFW hello world example.

In my project directory (I'm using vscode) there is a main.cpp file, and the glfw lib file I downloaded from glfw.org which I renamed to libglfw3.a (It's precompiled) I am using a MacBook Air M1.

I'm trying to compile it with this command:

clang -I /opt/homebrew/Cellar/glfw/3.3.7/include -L /Users//projects/ -l libglfw3.a main.cpp -o helloglfw

The output I get is:

ld: library not found for -llibglfw3.a
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I'm clearly dumb because for the life of me I can't see what I'm doing wrong...

Things I've tried:

1. linking to the homebrew version of glfw which contains a .dylib of glfw
2. tried linking libglfw3 (without the .a extension)
3. compiling to an object file and then linking with ld separately
4. using g++
5. Not using the -L flag and just pasting the full path into -l
6. Praying and restarting the pc just in case.
7. Waiting for it to fix itself

Some assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: You probably want `-lglfw3`. `lib` and `.a` are added automatically. Also `-l...` should be to the right of any `.c`/`.cpp`/`.o` files to have effect (at least on some linkers).

Comment: Just gave it a go with the main.cpp to the left of -L and -l and also added and removed the .a extension. No change :/

Comment: Check your compiler output for any warnings about ignoring incompatible libraries

Comment: @user2268909 You need to remove not only the `.a`, but also the `lib` prefix.

Answer (score 2):

OK SO! I fixed it. Apparently it works if there is NO SPACE between the -L and -l parameters.

so the command looks like this:

```
clang <source files> -I<Include Paths> -L<pathtolibs>-l<libs>
```

No clue why, but whatever I'm done...

Comment: That does not sound right. There _must_ be a space between `<pathtolibs>` and `-l`. Otherwise `-l` is considered part of the path and you are not actually linking any library at all. Now if you happen to start `<libs>` with a space as well, then `<libs>` will be considered a direct argument to `clang` (not an argument to an option). It will be interpreted like the files in `<souce file>`. You are probably lucky that this works here because you have `libglfw3.a` in the same directory from which you are compiling.

Comment: Th correct solution to the problem in your question is that `-l` does not take the full library name. It takes only the part between `lib` and `.a`, so it should be `-lglfw3` here. Your approach of effectively naming the `.a` as generic input file works as long as you know that you want to link a static library in your project directory, but the `-l` option is preferred if you are using a system-wide library or are linking a `.so`.

Comment: Alright, so I've tried to remove the lib and .a part, and it also finds the library, however it seems that I'm linking the wrong library alltogether because it doesn't find the required symbols. However that's okay because it now at least finds the file!